# How to redirect products from 'root' to new language subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have got a shop where all the products in the English version are directly in the `/en/-subdirectory`.
`www.example.com/en/productname-123`

Of course, not only products are in this `/en/-directory`, but also other categories. But I just want to redirect products (which all have an ID-number at the end, like 123 in the example).

So in the end I want to redirect
`www.example.com/en/productname-123` to `www.example.com/en/prodcucts/name-123`

Is this possible? How does the rewrite-rule for this scenario look like? (.htaccess, Apache)

Comment: So should that new URL be `/en/products/productname-123`? If not, you'd have to explain by what logic only `name` gets extracted from the original `productname`.

Comment: Also, what have you tried? URL rewriting is an already broadly discussed and well documented topic.

Comment: I voted to close this question because there is no example code. Please [edit] your post to include a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Alternately you could ask non-programming related questions about your website on [webmasters.se].